# python- moving files and checking duplicate names

Tags: python, filenames, file-move

I'm trying to make a code that can move files from one folder to another. 
For instance, I have files named 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg ... and so on in /test1/ folder and want to move those files to /test3/ folder if the same file name doesn't exist in /test2/.
So, if there's 0001.jpg both in folder /test1/ and /test2/ the file in /test1/ won't be moved to /test3/ folder but if there's 0002.jpg in /test1/ and not in /test2/, it moves to /test/3.

I've tried to write the code on my own but it won't work.
Can you please help with this?
Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import shutil

def Move_files(root_path, refer_path, out_path) :
    root_path_list= [file for file in os.listdir(root_path)]
    refer_path_list= [file for file in os.listdir(refer_path)]

    for file in root_path_list:
        if refer_path_list in root_path_list:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(os.listdir(root_path, file)),os.path.join(os.listdir(refer_path, file)))

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Move_files("D:\\Dataset\\test1", "D:\\Dataset\\test2", "D:\\Dataset\\test3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**: You can check if the file exists in your other directory using `os.path.exists`, and then only moving it if it does not already exist in `/test2/`:

```
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(refer_path, file)):
    shutil.move(os.path.join(os.listdir(root_path, file)),os.path.join(os.listdir(refer_path, file)))
```

Also, `os.listdir` only accepts one argument, the path to the directory of which you want to list the files. I think you want to change your `shutil.move` statement to this: `shutil.move(os.path.join(root_path, file),os.path.join(out_path, file))`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import os
import shutil

def Move_files(root_path, refer_path, out_path) :
    root_path_list= [file for file in os.listdir(root_path)]
    refer_path_list= [file for file in os.listdir(refer_path)]

    for file in root_path_list:
        if file not in refer_path_list:
            shutil.move(os.path.join(os.listdir(root_path, file)),os.path.join(os.listdir(out_path, file)))

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Move_files("D:\\Dataset\\test1", "D:\\Dataset\\test2", "D:\\Dataset\\test3")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` to find the difference between the file lists. I added an `isfile` check to ignore subdirectories (e.g., the "." and ".." directories in linux) and since `shutil.move` accepts a target directory, there is no need to build the target file name.

```
import os
import shutil

def Move_files(root_path, refer_path, out_path) :
    root_files = set(filename for filename in os.listdir(root_path)
        if os.path.isfile(filename))
    refer_files = set(filename for filename in os.listdir(refer_path)
        if os.path.isfile(filename))
    move_files = root_files - refer_files

    for file in move_files:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(root_path, file), out_path)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    Move_files("D:\\Dataset\\test1", "D:\\Dataset\\test2", "D:\\Dataset\\test3")
```